# How to replace null data with information from another table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Order_ID       ship_state     bill_state
   121            null            CA
   122            WA              IN    
   123            CA              OR
   124            null            FL
```

I have a query (below) that brings back these results (above). Order_ID, Ship_state, and bill_state are each in different tables. How can I modify my query so that it will populate the null ship_state with the corresponding bill_state? Some orders are shipped directly to the billing address, this makes the shipping fields null as they are left blank. I want to generate a list of ship to states.

```
SELECT  ca.STATE AS ship_state, 
        co.ID, 
        co.CUSTOMER_ID, 
        ca.ADDR_NO, 
        co.SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO, 
        c.STATE AS Bill_state, 
        c.NAME AS Bill_name, 
        ca.NAME AS Ship_name, 
        col.PART_ID, 
        col.ORDER_QTY, 
        ca.COUNTRY AS Ship_Country, 
        c.COUNTRY AS Bill_country, 
        co.ORDER_DATE
FROM dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE AS col 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.CUST_ADDRESS AS ca 
    FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.CUSTOMER AS c 
        INNER JOIN dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER AS co 
            ON c.ID = co.CUSTOMER_ID 
        ON ca.CUSTOMER_ID = co.CUSTOMER_ID 
        AND ca.ADDR_NO = co.SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO 
        AND ca.CUSTOMER_ID = c.ID 
    ON col.CUST_ORDER_ID = co.ID
WHERE co.ORDER_DATE > '2014-1-1'
  AND co.ID NOT LIKE 'rma%'
ORDER BY co.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function:

In your `SELECT`:

```
COALESCE(ca.STATE, c.STATE) AS ship_state
```

This will return the value of `c.STATE` if `ca.STATE` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ISNULL` function,

```
ISNULL(ca.State, c.State) As ship_state
```